# Excel formula for finding text in a string, to return text from cell in the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an odd question I could do with some expert advice on. I have two tables in Excel, in different sheets:

- in Table 1 I have a list of cities (C:C), each one with a unique numerical identifier (B:B), to account for cities that have the same name despite being in different countries (e.g. Dublin being in Ireland as well as California and Texas, for example);
- in Table 2 I have a list of "groups", each group being a continent/geographical area (B:B), each one with a list of cities that fit under that area, with the city name and its unique numerical identifier (D:D).

I now need to create Table 3 (in a separate sheet), which has the following layout:

- A:A has the names of the cities
- B:B asks is the city is part of a group (to return a YES or NO)
- C:C returns the name of the group, if the city is part of one, or just a blank cell, if the city is not part of a group.

I can't seem to think of formulas that can fit in Table 3's B and C columns. Would this be a case of INDEX and MATCH? Any help is greatly appreciated. (I've attached a screenshot as an example.)

[Screenshot from example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niHax.png)

**Edit**:

- I'm using Excel on Mac (Big Sur)
- My Excel version is the latest stable release, 16.47.

Comment: For Table 3's B column you could use something like `IF(LEN(VLOOKUP(…))=0, "Yes", "No")` and for 3's C column you could use `IFERROR(VLOOKUP(...),"")` to check for errors

Comment: What version of Excel? Also, might you be able to structure the data differently? Ideally you'll want information per city (including it's region) in a table, projects within another table, and a two-column table of project key vs city primary key per pairing.

Comment: Good point @JSmart523, I've just added the version in the text: v16.47 on Mac (Big Sur), it's the latest stable release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use this formula in N2 of your posted worksheet and copy down.

```
=INDEX(G2:G3,MATCH("*" & L2 &"*",I2:I3,0)).
```

Perhaps it makes sense to include the trailing opening parenthesis in the match:-

```
=INDEX(G2:G3,MATCH("*" & L2 &"(*",I2:I3,0)).
```

In cell M2 you might use a formula like this one:-

```
=IF(COUNTIF(C:C,L2)>1,"Yes","No")
```